# Hypothetical - Basic Med & Insurance

Tags: general-aviation, insurance, renters-insurance

I have a friend that needs some info...

He has a Basic Med certification in hand.  He takes a drug that is on the DNI list however it is admissible with a SI (SSRI).  His GP doctor signed his Basic Med form.  His GP doctor obviously knows the drug he is on and knows he is fully functional on the drug.  His GP doctor knows the drug is on the DNI list.

Given that background...

Would he have any possible insurance issues (renters or owners) if he were to ever get into an incident?  Could the insurance company deny a claim if he takes the drug even with a doctor's approval but WITHOUT the SI?

Thoughts?

Comment: Your friend is not legal to fly with BasicMed without having the SI. He still needs to get the SI. Not only would insurance deny your friend, but a ramp-check would find him flying without a valid medical.

Answer (score 1):

[BasicMed does not completely do away with SI's](https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/airmen_certification/basic_med/media/basicmed_faq.pdf) so your buddy may still need one [if he has never had one and has one of the 4 qualifying issues.](http://www.cogscreen.com/2017Seminar/OBRIEN-FAAPilotCertificationAPS2017.pdf)

[image]

To directly answer your question the insurance company may deny a claim on these grounds as they are somewhat free to deny claims as they see fit. There is [some more info from the FAA related to SSRI's here](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/media/Airman_Information_SSRI_Initial_Certification.pdf). Remember that basic med is about considering yourself fit to fly and being self conscious of your current state it does not set any protections for you that once you deem yourself fit to fly you actual are. Its a fairly new rule so only time will tell how cases play out in the future relating to issues.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the drug is treating though, if the drug is on the DNI, he *will* need an SI. The OP's friend would fall under Q11-A (never had an SI) because as I understand the OP's question, he may be eligible for one, but doesn't have one.

Comment: @RonBeyer that is what I thought, I have reworded it to be a bit more clear. The OP also does not state if the person has ever had and los a medical which could be an issue as well.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the feed back.  He had a third class in 2008 so within the look back period of Basic Med.  He started taking the drug around 2011.  He has never lost a medical.  He has never been medically deemed to have any of the 4 issues under Mental Health in Q11.   Thanks again.

Comment: OK let me ask like this.  If he had the SI totally legit all backed up.  Could insurance find a way to get out of paying the claim because of the drug even with the SI?  I understand this is all hypothetical.  I'm not asking you to speak for an insurance company.  I guess the better question is, How useful is renters insurance?  Do they look for any reason to get out of paying an indemnity?

Comment: @augerin there are a few to many variables there as that is pretty much completely situationally dependent, depends on the case, the insurer etc. I have renters insurance but cant say I have any experience making claims.

Comment: Understood.  Thanks again.  Probably his best bet to talk to a few insurance firms.  Insurance is easy to buy but not always easy to use.